# Matplotlib update one plot function when multiple functions plotted on same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a case where I plot multiple functions on one figure but want to update one function while not having to re-plot the other function.

A very simplistic example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)

ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

ax1.plot(x,1*np.sin(x),'b-')
ax2.plot(x,2*np.sin(x),'g-')
```

[image]

I want to clear/update the data plotted in `ax2` so that the data in `ax1` isn't cleared or needs to be replotted.

Using `ax2.clear()` or `ax2.cla()` both clear the entire figure.

Are there any suggestions on how I can either update just the data in `ax2` or a better way to control the plotting data for multiple functions on the same plot independently?

The actual case scenario plots satellite data (`ax1`) on a projected map with contour lines (`ax2`) overlayed. So the motivation is not to replot the satellite data due to time, but to keep the satellite data and update the contour plots (`ax2`) and save the figure at each step in a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_data) the data for the line in `ax2`:

```
l2, = ax2.plot(x, 2*np.sin(x),'g-')

l2.set_data((2*x, 3*np.sin(x)))
```

This will trigger replotting of the line in `ax2`, but axis scaling etc. isn't updated. Not sure if this is what you want.